# Name for type that has the same width and height

Tags: fonts, terminology

I know monospaced type (font) means all characters have the same width. Is there a similar name for fonts where all character have the same width and height?

Comment: I doubt there is an official name, but "square" fits. (On the minus side: browsing through www.fontsquirrel.com, it also seems to be used as "the opposite of 'round'". Oh well.)

Comment: As far as i know monospaced does actually not mean that every character has to have the same width, but it means that the horizontal space that every character occupies exclusively has to be the same. Example: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f0/Proportional-vs-monospace-v4.jpg The character `M` is wider than `a`, but they are both occupying the same amount of space (Horizontal and Vertical).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[As far as I know] **There is no name** for such fonts, because there are too few of them to create a categorization.

As mentioned in the comments, *square* or perhaps *geometric* could be possible search terms.

Your best option is to look for perfectly square uppercase fonts, as these are easier to find.

Here is a font with lowercase and a close-enough width-height ratio:

[**Panoptica**](https://www.fontshop.com/families/panoptica-doesburg/buy)

[image]

Comment: The reason you dont se lots of fonts that have uniform height is that capital leters by definition have equal height\* but small letters do not, it would be awfully hard to differentiate capital c from lower case c. *except they dont have to and accents + umlauts break havock on this.

Comment: @Yisela it looks like the Panoptica font link is a 404 now, but I presume it is this one? https://www.fonts.com/font/shinntype/panoptica/doesburg (paid font, ~$39)

Answer (score 1):

I think there is not! But feel free to make new declarations!

- **Mono-area font**: would be the weight or black.area for each character are the same
- **Mono-size font**: would be the same height characters
- **Mono-square font**: would be the one you will share with us - mono-space-size font (if you make one)

Answer (score -2):

Adobe calls those fonts "unicase".

Comment: Hmm. This seems to be fonts where there's only one case (normally that looks like uppercase). Not for the same size of width and height...