# Examples of "square" fonts

Tags: font-recommendation

I am looking for fonts with "square" letters, by which I mean fonts with both the same width and height. 
For example:
% we have a percentage here. To be square it should be wider, possibly with a "fatter" midline.

Comment: Related (not identical): [Name for type that has the same width and height](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/45260/name-for-type-that-has-the-same-width-and-height)

Comment: @user568458 It is asking if there is an official name for those, I'm asking for different font names that follow the criteria. Just to clarify.

Comment: Sure, that's why I said "Related (not identical)". Perfectly square fonts are very very rare. You can find near-square fonts by choosing wide fonts on a site that lets you filter by width ([Typekit](https://typekit.com/fonts) is one example, but that only covers Adobe's font library). Are you looking for perfectly square characters (in which case you'll also need to limit to monospaced fonts), or just near-square?

Comment: Searching MyFonts.com with keywords "square" and "monospaced" came up with an impressive list. Look at [iamblock](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/wearecolt/iamblock/) -- pretty amazing. I'm so tempted to give it a go.

Answer (score 4):

There's no official name for this, but there exists several square fonts that you can find in the below links

- http://www.1001fonts.com/monospaced+square-fonts.html
- http://www.fontspace.com/category/mono,monospace,square
- http://www.fontspace.com/category/mono,square,monospaced

[image: square fonts example]

There's also a font named [square](http://strlen.com/square/) which were made for games that are expected to show on a square grid

> **[Square is a TTF font intended for roguelike games](http://strlen.com/square/)**
>
> Roguelike games consist entirely of text in *grid cells*, but the problem is that ***most monospaced fonts are a lot higher than they are wide***, which means roguelikes either have non-square cells, or they have square cells and the characters don’t take up the entire box, neither of which looks very aesthetically pleasing.
>
> **Square has been designed to make characters fill a square space as evenly and uniformly as possible.** It is inspired upon the way Japanese characters always evenly fit a box, no matter their design. It foregoes the typical ascenders/descenders in lowercase characters, and instead makes lowercase characters look like a lighter version of uppercase characters.

[image: Square font]

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean Geometric font?

> From wikipedia: Geometric As their name suggests, Geometric sans-serif typefaces are based on geometric shapes, like near-perfect circle and square.

If this is what you mean you can use:
Futura
ITC Avant Garde
Gotham
In the free area you have Montserrat

Comment: I don't think geometric fonts are what the OP is looking for. I think it's "square" as the linked question in the comment suggests

Answer (score 0):

Try [HWT Konop](https://p22.com/family-Konop), a "monospaced font that is also square".