# If there are any square-grid Latin fonts

Tags: fonts, typography, grids

Pretty much every font I can think of is in a sort of portrait, paper-proportioned-ish grid, sort of like this:

```
 _
| |
|_|
```

A 1x2 grid fits tall letters like `l` and short letters at the bottom like `s`. This is the *rectangle* grid. But Chinese characters fit into a *square* grid:

```
 ___
|   |
|___|
```

So you can fit in characters such as 漢 which is like a ■ square.

I'm wondering if there are any such "square" fonts for Latin scripts. Just to be clear, I don't mean square, boxy font styles like [this](https://pinspiry.com/10-geometric-square-fonts-free-for-commercial-use/). I just mean some sort of squarely proportioned way of designing the Latin lower and uppercase characters *so it looks good*.

I haven't (1) found any examples yet, let alone (2) ones that look nice. I would like to see some nice examples if there are some out there.

Comment: The closest to what you are describing is probably what are called "monospace fonts".

Comment: I can think of Courier, which indeed is a monospace font, but also comes very close of being in a square aspect ratio. As a monospace, this means "so it looks good" is heavily challenged by having its `m` very narrow and its `i` very wide.

Comment: Fun fact: [there's no name for this type of font](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/45274/23061)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at Eurostile (super-elliptical letterforms) or Microgramma or Gotham. Trajan has a square base form (Caps only). Politene/Gridnik designed in 1974 by Wim Crouwel is based on a square grid. Gridnik is the digital revival of Politene. Epps Evans designed in 1969 by Timothy Epps is based on a 5 x 5 square grid...no longer available. New Alphabet by Wim Crouwel is a digital revival as well. Try The Foundry. McNeil, Paul, The Visual History of Type, 2017

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Optician Sans is a fully functional typeface based on the historical optotype letters, including numbers and special characters.   https://optician-sans.com

Answer (score 1):

[As I learned](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/45260/23061) when I asked what these fonts were called, [Panoptica](https://www.fontshop.com/families/panoptica/buy) is (close enough to) one:

[image]